# Unable to install Eclim for Eclipse in emacs

Tags: use-package, install

```
$ sudo apt install eclipse eclipse-jdt
```

Then, tried to install **eclim** using use-package in Emacs:

```
(use-package eclim
  :ensure t
  :config
   (require 'eclim)
   (setq eclimd-autostart t)
   (defun my-java-mode-hook ()
   (eclim-mode t))
   (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-java-mode-hook))
```

It seems, it did not install it. Then, I used terminal:

downloaded:

```
eclim_2.8.0.bin

debian# cd Downloads

debian# ./eclim_2.8.0.bin
```

Welcome to the installer for eclim 2.8.0.
Please specify the root directory of your eclipse install.
  Ex: /opt/eclipse 
      /usr/local/eclipse

```
> /home/tom/.eclipse/
```

**The eclipse launcher/executable could not be found in that directory**

eclipse is installed in `~/.eclipse`

**Also, how to configure executable directory path, using *use-package* in Emacs?**

Comment: See this: https://github.com/emacs-eclim/emacs-eclim - configure/modify custom-set-variables ...

Comment: Ian: I followed that link for installation... but unable to resolve

Comment: Try this: ```(setenv "PATH" (concat "/home/tom/.eclipse:"
                       (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/home/tom/.eclipse")``` before ```(use-package eclim...)```

Comment: Ian: I tried, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ian.

1. I manually downloaded the **eclipse** file directly from the site, eclipse.org. Then, installed it using GUI.
2. Then, manually downloaded the **eclim** file from the site, eclim.org. Then, I could give the path

> `/home/tom/eclipse/jee-2019-12/eclipse/`

3. Also, installed **emacs-eclim** by cloning the git.

Now, the **eclimd** is not starting. I will post the question separately,